# converting date in php returns different results depending on date format

Tags: php, datetime

What seemed to be a fairly standard date conversion is giving me unusual results. I want to get $pay_date into the 'j/d/Y' format, but can only get the correct date if the format is 'Y-m-d'.

Here's my code:

```
$payment = '2014-09-09';
$pay_date = strtotime("+1 month", strtotime($payment) );                    
$converter = date('j/d/Y', $pay_date );

echo $converter;
```

result: 9/09/2014 (should be 10/09/2014)

If I keep these variables, but change $converter to this format:

```
$converter = date('Y-m-d', $pay_date );
```

the result is correct - 2014-10-09

I also tried this:

```
$convert2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $pay_date)->format('j/d/Y');
echo $convert2;
```

result: 9/09/2014

but:

```
$convert2 = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $pay_date)->format('Y-m-d');
echo $convert2;
```

gives me the correct result: 2014-10-09

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` and `d` are the same formatting options, they both represent DAYs; from the [manual for PHP's date function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
d  Day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros  01 to 31
j  Day of the month without leading zeros         1 to 31
```

Use the format `'m/d/Y'`.

Comment: That's what happens when you spend too many hours at the computer. Thanks. Upvoted and I'll accept it as soon as the system lets me (5 min)

Comment: I won't forget. Thanks again. Now time for a break!